# Combining two queries with different tables and where clauses

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries that I need to combine. I've tried using a join and union, but nothing works. For instance, if I do a subquery my total column ends up being only ONE single value for all rows. What I want is for the total column to have different values (total # of ID's divided by month). Whereas the active column has certain conditions applied and is joined to the daily_kpis table (resulting in less ID's relative to the total column).

What's the best way to combine them? Also, I am using postgresql.

Update: To clarify, I want to know the total number of ID's for each month and then I only want to see the select # of ID's who have been active for that month. They are considered active if they are found bet any amount (anything more than zero). I would need the p table to the d table to see how many ID's were betting money. But for the total column, I DONT want to do a join and I just want to see the total per month of ID's in the p table.

```
Query 1
SELECT date_part('month', signup_date) as month, count(DISTINCT(p.cage_player_id)) as active
FROM player_signup as p
JOIN daily_kpis as d ON d.cage_player_id = p.cage_player_id
WHERE slot_bet_amount > 0
OR ld_bet_amount > 0 
OR table_bet_amount > 0 
GROUP BY date_part('month', signup_date)
ORDER BY date_part('month', signup_date) ASC

Query 2
SELECT count(cage_player_id) as total
FROM player_signup
GROUP BY date_part('month', signup_date)
ORDER BY date_part('month', signup_date) ASC
```

Here is what each query gives me as a result. I would just like to append the total column to the month and active column.

**Query 1** 
[Query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz9Lm.png)

**Query 2**
[Query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8qL9.png)

Comment: Apologies! Ignore the count(f.cage_player_id) as total in the 1st query

Comment: Rocio, please don't have the above comment, Instead use the edit tag (under the question) and actually update the question.

Answer (score 0):

With out actual table definitions nor sample data with results I can only hope I understand what you need. But if I understand correct the the following should work. I've built the resulting query via CTEs leaving your queries in tact as much as possible. Additionally, without data I assumed it's possible for them to NOT have the same months.

```
 with mon_list (mon) as
     (select date_part('month',date '2020-01-01' + lev * interval '1 month')
        from generate_series ( 0, 11) t(lev)
     )  
   , player_count (mon, player_cnt) as 
     ( select  date_part('month', signup_date),count(cage_player_id)
         from player_signup
        group by date_part('month', signup_date)
     )
   , kpi_count (mon, active,total) as
     (select date_part('month', signup_date)  
           , count(p.cage_player_id) 
           , count(d.cage_player_id)  
        from player_signup as p
        join daily_kpis as d on d.cage_player_id = p.cage_player_id
       where slot_bet_amount > 0
         and ld_bet_amount > 0 
         and table_bet_amount > 0 
       group by date_part('month', signup_date)
     ) 
select ml.mon                  "Month"
     , coalesce(kpi.active,0)  "Active"
     , coalesce(kpi.total,0)   "Total" 
     , coalesce(pc.player_cnt) "Players"
  from mon_list          ml
  left join player_count pc  on (pc.mon  = ml.mon)
  left join kpi_count    kpi on (kpi.mon = ml.mon)
 order by ml.mon;
```

Comment: Hi! I have updated the question above. Let me know if that makes more sense. Is there a simple way of doing this with an INSERT? Sorry I am a bit of newbie

Comment: Also, would a UNION also make sense in this case? I keep trying to use it but I think I may be doing something wrong

Comment: A UNION would not add a column, it would add a row. You would have to adjust what's selected so both side of the union have the same number and type of columns. You don't want to do a join - why not?

Comment: I see what you mean now! I think I still have to look at what you provided to understand it since I'm a little bit confused. Also, if I wanted to created a column now that divided column Active by Players, how could I do that?